# Push notification message customization?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am working on chat application. Whenever someone send me a message I receive a push notification with text "A send a message to you".But sometimes I receive push with text "You have 4 new messages".(4 is the variable number). Server team claims that they are not sending this type of message.Just wanted to know if apple customize the message in any case.

Answer (score 0):

**No, Apple doesn't do that.**

It has to be your server developers or some third party library they are using to send Push Notifications.

Comment: Server is using service of azure. Do you think Azure might be doing this.?

Comment: I haven't got my hands on Azure yet, but it is possible.